# Adding PATH to RStudio’s path

Tags: r, rstudio

I am running RStudio on MacOS and need to use some custom command line tools like `csvcut` (part of `csvkit`) for a function that multiple people on our team will use on their machines.

If I run a `system('pip install csvcut)` (I am using this command as an example; normally, I’d run `csvcut`) from R in the terminal, it works (checks if the last version has been installed, etc.), just like if I do it from the command line terminal.

If I do the same thing from within RStudio:

```
> system('pip install csvkit')
sh: pip: command not found
```

If I do `which pip` in the terminal and copy-paste the address into RStudio, it works:

```
system('/anaconda3/anaconda/bin/pip install csvkit')
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): csvkit in /anaconda3/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages
# etc.
```

^ that’s the output if I simply do `system('pipinstall csvkit')` from R in the terminal.

Unfortunately, I can’t even run `which pip` from within RStudio. (Also, I couldn’t automatically `pip install csvkit` for others’ machines, since it requires sudo access.) If there was a way to point RStudio to R’s path, that would be easier.

I found instructions on some website that said to create a `.Renviron` file and have a `R_LIBS_USER=~/R/library` line in it, but that didn’t help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this line to your .Renviron file:

```
PATH=/anaconda3/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: that didn’t work. although, when I type `system(‘env’)` in my RStudio console, I get the output with this line: `PATH=/anaconda3/anaconda/bin;$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin`

Comment: try replacing `;` with a `:`

Comment: We use .Rprofile at work. If I add that line there, would that work as well?

Comment: This didn't work for me in .Renviron.  I had to do do ${PATH} ... with the braces as documented here... "Note that the braces are essential: $HOME will not be interpreted"  https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/lib/R/library/base/html/Startup.html

Comment: @petegordon suggestion is crucial. If you do not use the braces, the `$PATH` variable is not expanded.