# Can I change the location of Homebrew FFTW install? R can't seem to read FFTW3.h file located in Cellar folder

Tags: r, homebrew, fftw

I'm trying to install wholebrain by Daniel Fürth, following the instructions on the macosX install page ([available here](http://www.wholebrainsoftware.org/cms/installing-wholebrain-on-mac-osx/#step1)). I am running MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2, R 4.1.2, and RStudio 2021.09.1.

Unfortunately, the program is not straight-forward to install and requires significant developer tools to work correctly. I'm not a programmer and have almost no experience with coding, so I've been mucking through the instructions for two days now trying to get the install to work correctly and I'm firmly stuck on the final step.

In RS, when I run, `devtools::install_github("tractatus/wholebrain", INSTALL_opts=c("--no-multiarch"))` I get the following error message:

`/bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found filter.cpp:9:10: fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found #include "fftw3.h" ^~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated. make: *** [filter.o] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘wholebrain’`

I have been trying to figure out what this means for quite awhile now and I think I've narrowed it down to R is not reading the location of the fftw header file from where it was installed by Homebrew. (I could be totally wrong, again- not a programmer)

From what I understand, Homebrew always installs under opt/homebrew/cellar. And, in fact, in there is the compiled fftw program with the needed "fftw3.h" file. But for some reason, RStudio is not able to find and read the file in that location.

From random googling and reading of other posted issues, I think that RStudio may expect the file to be under usr/local/include. Can I just copy and paste the header file into that folder? Or will I be screwing something up if I do that? I am totally intimidated by fftw's description of manual compilation so I don't really want to attempt that. Is there a way to change where R is looking for that header file? I already set my wd to "/" so shouldn't R be able to access any folder on my computer?

Comment: Try `brew install pkg-config` first, followed by `hash -r` so that your shell can find `pkg-config` command.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to have fixed the issue. R still says pkg-config: command not found and gives the same error about the header file.

Comment: Be advised I don't use/know R, but it seems when you use `system()` in R, it invokes `sh` as the shell and that shell cannot find `pkg-config`. So I deduce that the PATH that R's `sh` uses doesn't include `/opt/homebrew/bin` which is why it cannot find `pkg-config` in that directory. To test my theory, maybe you could go into R and run `system('echo $PATH')` and see if the **homebrew** stuff is in there?

Comment: Yes, I think you're exactly right about that, Mark. I think R can't 'see' the Homebrew folders. Here is what I get as output when I use the code you suggested ```/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/postback```

Comment: I still don't use R, but think you could add the **homebrew** PATH using this answer and heeding the comments about curly braces... https://stackoverflow.com/a/32403524/2836621

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to get it to work at long last!!

Answer (score 2):

I want to post an answer here for anyone who comes after me with the same issue. It came down to **RStudio** not recognizing the programs **Homebrew** had installed because it wasn't reading the file location where **Homebrew** saves them. **Homebrew** always installs programs in `/opt/homebrew/...` Here is what I had to do:

In **RStudio**, open your Renviron file using this command: `usethis::edit_r_environ()`

In the file that opens (which for me was totally blank), type: `PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:${PATH}`, or whatever your particular path you want prepended to the Renviron path is.

Quit **RStudio** and, when prompted, save. Re-open **RStudio** and run `Sys.getenv("PATH")` to check. Your new path (in the example above, '/opt/homebrew/bin') should now be prepended to the list of paths that **RStudio** will use when looking for programs/files. For me this now looks like `/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/postback`

Finally, I want to say thank you very much to Mark Setchell who really helped point me in the correct direction!

Comment: Cool, well done! And thank you for sharing your efforts back with the StackOverflow community. Good luck with your project.